# Как защитить веб-приложение лицензией?

Tags: лицензирование

Разработал приложение и хочу присвоить себе право на код, чтобы в случае копирования и использования в коммерческих целях, я мог пойти в суд.

Comment: В большинстве стран у Вас уже автоматом есть право на код. Его не нужно получать.

Comment: @KoVadim, получать не надо, а вот доказывать его надо, если речь про суд. См. ответ ниже.

Comment: Ваш ответ сильно субъективный и не является ответом. Я его читаю так - "не пытайтесь".

Comment: Есть регистрация в реестр российского ПО

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо. 1) я не юрист, поэтому ответ, конечно, субъективен, (да и у того он таким будет) но у меня есть определённые знания в этой области, и я неплохо знаю общую судебную практику в РФ. У вас есть другие знания о ситуации с защитой прав на ПО? (Не обязательно про РФ, можно и по практике украинской). 2) Из него не следует "не пытайтесь". Из него должно следовать: "продумайте процесс так, чтобы это не было впустую (т.е. регистрацию сделать правильно), чтобы можно было всё решить ещё до суда, и чтобы ваши затраты на действия не превысили ожидаемые доходы". Добавлю это в ответ.

Comment: @eri, реестр российского ПО - это не о том. Этот реестр используют для доказательства, что ПО можно использовать в госучреждениях и т.д. В суде удивятся, если вместо регистрации по ГК вы эту регистрацию предъявите. Да и, как понимаю, там ещё и сложнее, чем по ГК регистрировать. Придется кое-что доказывать.

Comment: но такая запись докажет авторство и принадлежность кода.

Comment: 1262 ГК РФ почитаю, но ГК не подходит для юридических лиц

Comment: Кстати, если сделать программу открытой и бесплатной, то на ней можно заработать больше.) но это если она не имеет аналогов

Comment: @eri, 1) одна только запись не докажет, её мало. Там еще сам код нужен, возможно ещё что-то. Не знаю, чтобы на практике применяли такой способ доказательства. Если вы знакомы с практикой юридической, то скажите, спорить особо не буду.  2) Вы почему так решили по поводу ГК? :-)) Пункт 1 ст.2 ГК РФ утверждает прямо противоположное. Да и весь мой опыт тоже.

Comment: код передается на регистрацию

Comment: @eri, если в результате работы по занесению в регистр российского ПО код передается на ту же регистрацию, что и по 1262 ГК, то придётся выполнить условия обоих процессов. Это просто неэффективный алгоритм:-), если нужна только регистрация для доказательства прав.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу (просто по частотной вероятности и потому, что автор не называет страну), что автор вопроса из России, и отвечу относительно её законодательства.
Отмечу при этом, что этот сайт не лучшее место для такого вопроса.

Вчерне могу сказать следующее:

**Вывод:** продумайте процесс так, чтобы это не было впустую (т.е. регистрацию надо сделать правильно), чтобы можно было всё решить ещё до суда, и чтобы ваши затраты на действия не превысили ожидаемые доходы.

**Подробнее:**

1. Право у вас возникнет с момента создания кода. Но это на 100% только если вы код разработали сами, не работая в это время на кого-либо другого. В других случаях возможны нюансы. Например, учтите, что ряд компаний прямо указывает в трудовых договорах, что все коды, созданные сотрудником, независимо от того в рабочее ли время это делалось, принадлежат компании. Можно оспорить в суде, но не самый лёгкий процесс и шансы не очень понятны.
2. Предположу, что патент вы брать не собираетесь. Да и саму программу патентом в РФ не защитить, потребуется защищать алгоритм. Сложно и дороже, чем п.3.
3. В варианте без патента для защиты в суде по текущей практике требуется доказать дату создания и авторство. Для этого обычно используют Государственную регистрацию программ для ЭВМ и баз данных согласно  Статье 1262 ГК РФ (советую ознакомиться с ней). Подходить к регистрации надо вдумчиво, заранее обдумав, чем можно будет доказать, что ответчиком использован именно этот код.
4. Слово "лицензия" применимо не к защите ваших прав, а к правам на использование вашего ПО у тех, кто их у вас или ваших дистрибьюторов получил.
5. Учтите, что суд дело не самое дешевое, юристы - не самое недорогое удовольствие, а по судебной практике расходы на них даже при выигрыше дела не компенсируются полностью, как правило.

Можете так же почитать статьи тут, хотя сама тема пошире будет:

https://skillbox.ru/media/code/kak-zashchitit-kompyuternuyu-programmu-s-tochki-zreniya-prava-chast-1/

https://skillbox.ru/media/code/kak-zashchitit-kompyuternuyu-programmu-s-tochki-zreniya-prava-chast-ii/

*Ограничение ответственности:* приведённое выше является моим  субъективным мнением и не является персональной юридической рекомендацией. Не принимаются никакие претензии об убытках и  т.д. в любой форме вследствие следования или не следования кем бы то ни было данной рекомендации. При необходимости рекомендации для реальных действий нужно обратиться к юристу.